# EmberJS as keyword in handlebars template

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, ember-cli

I have referred to the EmberJS official guide to understand the usage of "as" keyword in handlebars template. But I find it very confusing.

What does this do, in relation to passing values to component, yield, etc?

Comment: like {{#each somethings as something  }} ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If component yields some value, `as` keyword can be used to refer to it. I can offer following example.

Component's file:

```
//yield-something.js
import Component from '@ember/component';

/**
 * This component just yields something
 *
 * @module
 * @augments Ember.Component
 */
export default Component.extend({
    /**
     * Something to yield
     */
    something: undefined
});
```

Component's template's file:

```
{{yield something}}
```

Usage:

```
{{#yield-something something=(hash name='Joe') as |data|}}
  Hello {{data.name}}
{{/yield-something}}
```

This component yields what I pass to it and then I use that as `data` (`hash` helper creates an object from passed parameters). This example could look weird, but it's short and I hope it helps. Practical usage of `yield` and `as` is to pass some object or value created by component to nested components/template. Yield are not limited to just one parameter, you can yield few values `{{yield 'Hello' 'World' 123}}` and then use them like this: `{{#component-name as |val1 val2 val3|}}`

You can take a look how [ember-leaflet](https://github.com/miguelcobain/ember-leaflet#examples) uses it to pass outer layers to nested. Yield is not used in every component. In fact, if you are new to ember you may not have a need to use yield, unless you need to build complex set of components (like ember-leaflet).

Comment: Awesome answer...Exactly what I was looking for....Just 2 follow-up questions..
1. .Can a component have yields in multiple places (i.e. in the component's hbs file). If yes, how does the mapping happen when using the as keyword from the consuming code ?
2. In the ember-leaflet example, I saw 'this' keyword used in the component template. What does this represent when the component is consumed ?
{{yield (hash
    tile=(component "tile-layer" parentComponent=this)
)}}

Comment: @testndtv 1. Yes, component may have multiple yields, [example](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/05/03/reusable-page-layouts-ember/) 2. `this` in component's template refers to component's instance.

Comment: Awesome as always...Really loved your precise answers !! Thanks again...

Comment: I have accepted the answer..But just had last questions on the example you had given..
1. For mapping the yield (between component & consuming code), it prints even though it is referred via the condition (i.e. it maps to title where code says {{#if section.isTitle}}. I was thinking it should have worked with {{section.isTitle}}) So was confused how that works

2. Using {{section.title}} does not work ? Why do we have to use {{section.isTitle}} ?

Thanks a lot...

Comment: @testndtv not sure I understood your question. Each time ember sees `yield` in component's template, it renders and inserts nested template, passing what was yielded to it (and `as` is used to give that object a name). In that example they yield an object which has `isTitle` property or `isFormGroups` property or some other property. Nested template checks what property that object has and renders needed part. Maybe this example would be easier https://ember-twiddle.com/add9fc188e2095c53f4d3fb1bb3f2bce?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.person-component-2.hbs

Comment: Hey again...On this page (https://github.com/ciena-blueplanet/ember-block-slots), it says " since only a single yield is available", got confused what that really means ? Is that referring to an earlier Ember version ?

Comment: @testndtv no idea, only author of that repo could know

Answer (score 0):

To use the `as` keyword in another template, we'd want to declare it in the original component using `hash` first.

For example, we have a component called `foo-a`. (also learned from hard lesson that ember doesn't allow one word as the name for a component. We need at least 1 dash to avoid conflict with future html changes. )

```js
//`foo-a.js` 
export default Component.extend({
   init() {},
   method1() {
      return 'blah';
   }
});
```

```
//`foo-a.hbs`
{{yield}}
```

the parent component `bar-b.hbs` looks like

```
{{#foo-a}}
  <div> This is the content I want to display
   </div>
{{/foo}}
```

`bar-b` will render: 
This is the content I want to display.

**Now** say we want to use `foo-a` in `bar-b`, and we want to use `method1` when we are passing content into `foo-a`, we'll need to do the following change `foo-a.hbs` to make it happen:

```
{{yield (hash method1=method1)}}
```

and now the `bar-b.hbs` looks like

```
{{#foo-a as |fooArgs|}}
  <div> This is the content I want to display, but use a method from `foo-a`. 
    I want to call `method1` in `foo-a` component now. and this is the syntax: 
    {{fooArgs.method1}}
   </div>
{{/foo}}
```

now we can see the following text rendered by `bar-b`:
This is the content I want to display, but use a method from `foo-a`. I want to call `method1` in `foo-a` component now. and this is the syntax: blah